# Transform a dataframe with column value as column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like this

```
         date     price num_floors    house
1  2023-01-01  94.30076          3        A
2  2023-01-01  95.58771          2        B
3  2023-01-02 102.78559          1        C
4  2023-01-03  93.29053          3        D
```

and I want to change it, so that each column contains the prices and num_floors for all houses for a given date. For one column,  the first two rows of a column refer to the first house, the next two to the second house. The remaining entries without data are filled with the missing value NaN.

Now, I want to transform the above dataframe, so that it has a similar structure as the following:

```
  2023-01-01    2023-01-02  2023-01-03
1   94.30076     102.78559    93.29053
2          3             1           3         
3   95.58771            NA          NA
4          2            NA          NA
```

Each column contains the prices and num_floors for all houses for a given date. For one column,  the first two rows of a column refer to the first house, the next two to the second house. The remaining entries without data are filled with the missing value NaN.

I tried with pivot_wider. It does not work:

```
# Pivot the dataframe
df_transformed <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date,
              values_from = c(price, num_floors),
              values_fill = NaN)
```

Comment: I think you will need a column for "house" in the data frame.  It will be impossible for house 1 and house 2 to be distinguished without this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot to long format first, and then go wide after adding a row number.

```
pivot_wider(
  pivot_longer(df, -date) %>% mutate(n=row_number(), .by=date),
  id_cols = n, names_from=date, values_from = value
) %>% select(-n)
```

Output:

```
  `2023-01-01` `2023-01-02` `2023-01-03`
         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1         94.3         103.         93.3
2          3             1           3  
3         95.6          NA          NA  
4          2            NA          NA
```

(I will note that this transformation seem unlikely to be the optimal way to represent your data).

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to do it in python?

Comment: sure, but you should pose a new question, with the correct python tag, etc